# How to handle long press with ViewGroup while handling tap with it's children views?

Tags: android, gesture, touch-event

I have a view group that has several children. I want to open menu on long press any part of that view group while being able to tap it's children and handle this tap by them. How can I implement that behavior?

I tried to use `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `SimpleGestureListener`, but `onLongPress` doesn't return anything, so when I remove finger, it's still handled by it's children.

Best way I could achieve this is to put `onLongPressListeners` on children views and open menu from them, but it's not the best way. Also I have some views that shouldn't know about menu and their view group at all.

UPDATE:

Adding some code.

```
@OnClick(R.id.comment_header)
public void commentHeaderClicked() {
    if (userClickedListener != null) {
        if (comment != null) {
            userClickedListener.onUserClicked(comment.getUser());
        }
    }
}

@OnLongClick(R.id.comment_container)
public boolean commentLongClick() {
    if (commentLongClickListener != null) {
        commentLongClickListener.onCommentLongClick(commentId,
                isMine,
                isMyPost);
    }
    return true;

}
```

The problem is, that if there is any interested in click view, long click for `ViewGroup` is ignored.

Comment: I would imagine that this will be difficult to implement at best. I would tend to agree with your existing answer, that you would need to intercept the touch events and make all the calculations and decisions in the `ViewGroup` for everything (clicks, long-clicks, etc.). That strikes me as being rather fragile. Personally, I would not be attempting to do what you are describing. The "best" place I can suggest that you look for ideas would be in `ListView`/`AbsListView`, to see how they handle long-clicks on rows.